# Inserting multiple values from a form to an array

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I have a form with multiple fields like that:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
```

I am trying to insert submit that form and those values to an array in database:

```
<?php 

$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];

    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO main (name) VALUES ('$name')");
    $i++;
  } 
?>
```

This is giving me error "mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given"

I also tried replacing the query with:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE main
SET name='$name'
WHERE id=2");
```

But I think this is not actually posting 3 values of name to an array. Instead its posting only one.

I tried to use multiple codes that I found on this website but I still can't figure it out!

Comment: You do need to add `$connect` to your first call to `mysqli_query` but why did you add the `WHERE` condition to your second one?

Comment: @Nick I had two rows with id=1 and id=2. I thought that if I am going to specify an id its going to insert it into one row as an array. I am aware that this is probably wrong anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through `$_POST`, there is no need to do that, try looping through `$_POST['name']`, like this:

If the file rendering the form is the same one receiving the post you must first validate a post has been made before attempting to loop through `'name'`.

```
if(array_key_exists('name', $_POST){
  foreach($_POST['name'] as $name){
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO main (name) VALUES 
  ('$name')");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alberto, So I actually tried doing something like that before but it is giving me this error: "Notice: Undefined index: name" and this one "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". Cheers.

Comment: Changed the answer since i suspect you may be using the same file/url to render the form and process the insert. Please confirm if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO main (name) VALUES ('".$name."')");
```

Here `$connect` is your database connection. you need to specify this connection somewhere earlier in your code.